# Cognos samesite attribute to none causing cognos mashup auth url to fail

Tags: cognos-11

I am using cognos domain inside a iframe in another domain. I added all the CSP derivates and cognos is loading in iframe in different domain. But login was not happening..
From cognos documentation i see we can set Configuration.cookieSameSite to None and followed that.. This fixed the login issue.

But we had a mashup rest url for another functionality, (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mashup-using-rest-url-logon-ibm-cognos-analytics-server (Second method) which is failing after the above mentioned change with below error :

> Response: <rds:error
> xmlns:rds="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/rds/types/2">rds:messageRDS-ERR-1020
> The currently provided credentials are invalid. Please provide the
> logon credentials.</rds:message></rds:error>`

I used http://localhost:9300/..... for mashup url..